# ¿Como Deserializo un Json Matriz?

Tags: c#, json

Tengo estos dos métodos:

```
public async Task<List<PullRequest>> GetPullRequests(string name, string repoName)
{
    var response = await GetHttpClient().GetAsync($"{Host}/repos/{name}/{repoName}/pulls");
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PullRequest>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}

public async Task<List<Repository>> GetRepositories(string name)             
{            
    var response = await GetHttpClient().GetAsync($"{Host}/orgs/{name}/repos");
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Repository>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Pero me salta este error cuando intento ejecutarlo:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Evaluator.Model.Repository]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'message', line 1, position
>   11.

¿Como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: ¿Podrías, por favor, agregar el JSON que esperas deserializar? Esto para conocer la estructura del mismo y sugerir una solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje esta indicando que no es un array o lista lo que quieres deserializar, sino que es un objeto simples, quizas no debas usar `List<Repository>` sino solo `Repository`, recupera el json que obtienes en un string y analizalo

Usa

```
var response = await GetHttpClient().GetAsync($"{Host}/orgs/{name}/repos");
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

lleva ese string a una tool como ser

> http://json2csharp.com/

para obtener la estructura de clases que realmente mapea con el json que obtienes